# Optimization on the multinomial manifolds of stochastic non-square matrices

Tags: optimization

Thanks for note! So I have an optimization problem with simple form but the decision variable is a large-scale matrix. My problem is similar to a existing problem [here](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/23940/optimization-on-the-manifold-of-stochastic-matrices/36335#36335) about multinomial manifolds and my objective function is simpler than the counterpart in that problem. The decision variable $\mathbf T \in {\bf R}^{1300\times 3100}$ is a stochastic matrix (each row sums to 1) with non-negative elements. $\mathbf S \in {\bf R}^{600\times 1300}$ is a known constant matrix with non-negative elements. $\mathbf L \in {\bf R}^{3100\times 9000}$ is a known constant sparse matrix. There are exactly one $1$ and one $-1$ in each column of $\mathbf L $, so the column sum of $\mathbf L $ is equal to $0$ for every column. Let $\mathbf X$ denote  the product of above three matrices, i.e. $\mathbf X=\mathbf S\mathbf T\mathbf L$. The optimization problem is below.
$$
\text{minimize}\hspace{3mm}f(\mathbf T)=\sum_{i=1}^{600}\sum_{j=1}^{9000}|\mathrm X_{ij}| 
$$
$$
\text{subject to}\hspace{19mm}\mathbf T{\bf 1}=\bf{1}
$$
$$
\hspace{39mm}\mathrm   T_{ij}>0
$$
The optimization function means I expect to obtain a matrix $\mathbf X$ as similar to zero matrix as possible, so it can be replaced by minimizing Frobenius norm of $\mathbf X$ or other similar forms.  As far as I know, my problem resembles optimal transport in some ways. In addition, there may be some trick to reduce the amount of computation and cost of storage given the special nature of matrix $\mathbf L$. I'm doubting whether the manopt toolbox in Matlab [here](https://www.manopt.org/reference/manopt/manifolds/multinomial/multinomialfactory.html) is capable of dealing with this large-scale optimization problem (speed is not so important). I have thought that a python package named pymanopt [here](https://www.pymanopt.org/) might work but the multinomial manifolds is not currently supported by pymanopt. I'm planning to employ a feasible algorithm or a computation environment to solve this optimization task. If there are ideas to make my mission possible, what would be the best approach here? Thanks very much for any advice or comments.

Comment: You'll want to replace the last constraint by $T_{ij}\ge 0$. Without the inequality, you are optimizing over an open set and you can't guarantee that there is a solution.

Comment: Furthermore, this is just a linear program, though a fairly large one. If you introduce slack variables, you'll realize that you can rewrite the problem in terms of the sum of slack variables, and you end up with a whole bunch of inequalities that are all linear in the $X_{ij}$ and because $X$ is linear in your primary variable $T$, these are all linear constraints in $T$.

Comment: What you said is very helpful, I need to add slack variables $u_{ij}$, $v_{ij}$, and constraints $u_{ij}\geq 0$, $v_{ij}\geq 0$, $u_{ij}-v_{ij}=X_{ij}$. Furthermore, I should rewrite $f(\mathbf T)$ as $f(\mathbf T)=\sum_{i=1}^{600}\sum_{j=1}^{9000}(u_{ij}+v_{ij})$.

Comment: I will replace the last constraint by $T_{ij}\geq 0$. Thanks. It now appears that I should look for a software to implement the computation. I will try to do, and any advice for efficient computation is adorable.

Comment: It's just a linear program after reformulation. There should be plenty of software around for that.

Comment: I thought about solving this optimization problem using Gurobi. Now I am attempting to set up the optimization model in Gurobi through Python to run it in Linux like Vinayak Suresh did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55007200/trying-to-solve-a-very-large-scale-linear-program-with-gurobi), but he hasn't told if his linear programming problem is solved successfully by Gurobi.

Comment: My problem has about $600\times 9000\times 2+1300\times 3100=14830000$ variables and  $600\times 9000\times 3+1300\times 3100+1300=20231300$ constraints. so it is very-large-scale and may be a difficult or even infeasible optimization task to fulfil on a PC with 40GB memory.

Comment: Yes, that's quite a large problem. But a linear program is about the best case to have for such a large problem, any other formulation would be equally impossible to solve.

Answer (score 1):

When all elements of $\mathbf T$ are equal to a same constant, the optimal objective value is $0$. I shouldn't have asked that question. Thanks.